# Ionic2 disabling checked checkbox

Tags: ionic2

I have a dataservice with todo's, if someone else clicked the checkbox (at another device) I want to disable it with state 'checked'.

My problem is that even the checked state is true, it turns to unchecked in the ui when it was switched to 'checked AND disabled'

for me it seems like a bug, but maybe I missed somewhat?

thx...
Pitt

Comment: Do you found any workaround for this?

Comment: Not really, for now I made the font with ngIf strikethrough, I don't want to dive in the SASS...

Comment: With Ionic 3 it solved ...

Comment: great... will check it out soon.